# How do you share files on an Ubuntu host with a Windows guest in VMWare

Tags: vmware

I have a VMWare Workstation 12 Player running Windows 7 guest on an Ubuntu host. I want a certain file on my Ubuntu host to be accessible by the Windows guest, but I cannot find any good guide on how to achieve this. The only one I found is this [guide from VMWare's website](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_running9.html), but it not comprehensible for someone like I who is not a techie, and new to Linux-systems:

> **Sharing Files by Connecting to a Windows System from a Linux System**
>
> [...]
>
> 4) Add the Windows system's host name and IP address to the hosts file, if the system cannot be found by name.
>
> 5) Mount the Windows share on your Linux system. Enter the following command all on one line.
>
> `mount -t smbfs -o username=<Windows system user account>,password=<password> //win2k/docs /mnt/docs`

I don't know if the system can be found by name or not. I don't know how to figure out the windows system's host name and IP address. And I don't know what to write in the field `<Windows System user account>`.

There is a lot of information on Windows hosts and Ubuntu guests on both Stack Exchange and other sites, but none for Ubuntu hosts.